# Ошибка при выполнении pip install zip

Tags: python-3.6, pip

Windows 10 x32
Python 3.6.5 x32 бита. При исполении команды `pip install zip` выдает ошибку:

```
*ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\anon4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y19ekf4\wsgiref\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    import ez_setup
  File "C:\Users\anon4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y19ekf4\wsgiref\ez_setup\__init__.py", line 170
    print "Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed."
                             ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Setuptools version",version,"or greater has been installed.")?
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\anon4\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-_y19ekf4\wsgiref\*
```

Что делать?

Comment: Наверно переустановить питон, раз у вас стандартная библиотека битая и модуль wsgiref отсутствует

Comment: А вообще зачем вам pip install zip?

Comment: Переустанавливал, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://travis-ci.org/kdheepak/zip) сказано, что это модуль для Python 2.7. Установить на Python 3 его невозможно.